# How do I do a JPQL SubQuery?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

It is possible to do the equivalent of this sql query in JPQL?

```
SELECT * 
 FROM COUNTRIES c WHERE COUNTRY_ID IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY_ID 
   FROM PORTS p 
   WHERE p.COUNTRY_ID = c.COUNTRY_ID AND STATE = 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to test it with [IN](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_in) and [subquery](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries) since both do work in JPQL (according to syntax reference they do work together). You may also look at [MEMBER OF expressions](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_collection_member).

But there is a better approach in my opinion. Such queries are called correlated sub-queries and one can always re-write them using EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES c WHERE 
EXISTS (
        SELECT 'found' FROM PORTS p 
        WHERE p.COUNTRY_ID = c.COUNTRY_ID AND STATE = 'A'
)
```

JPQL supports [EXISTS with subqueries](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_exists).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to use `subquery` with `IN` operator in JPQL. I had a similar usecase and it worked for me. My query was as follows.

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Group g WHERE g.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT m.groupId FROM Member m WHERE m.id IN (?1))")
List<Group> findAllGroupsOfMembers(List<BigInteger> memberIds);
```