# JPQL Subquery - Exception this expression has an invalid table in this context

Tags: java, jpa, subquery, jpql

I have a (inneficient, but working) T-SQL (sub)query

```
SELECT * FROM DIAGE.ade.UorPos WHERE Prefixo IN
  (SELECT PrefixoJurisdicionada FROM DIAGE.ade.Jurisdicionadas WHERE Prefixo =
    (SELECT Prefixo FROM DIAGE.ade.Jurisdicionadas WHERE PrefixoJurisdicionada = 8922)) 
AND CodComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)
```

which I've build the correspondent JPQL

```
SELECT u FROM UorPos u WHERE u.prefixo IN 
  (SELECT j.prefixoJurisdicionada FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixo = 
    (SELECT j.prefixo FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixoJurisdicionada = :prefixo)) 
AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)
```

Despite compiling, when running launches the Exception:

```
[...]
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [DIAGE.ade.Prefixos.Prefixo] in this 
expression has an invalid table in this context.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="UorPos.findUorPosExecutivosByPrefixo" 
referenceClass=UorPos jpql="SELECT u FROM UorPos u WHERE u.prefixo IN 
(SELECT j.prefixoJurisdicionada FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixo = 
(SELECT j.prefixo FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixoJurisdicionada = 
:prefixo)) AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)") at 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException. invalidTableForFieldInExpression (QueryException.java:749)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.validateNode(FieldExpression.java:296)
at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression.normalize(Expression.java:3275)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.normalize(DataExpression.java:369)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.normalize(FieldExpression.java:223)
```

I've made some research and, in my understanding, my JPQL query is ok.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Some links I've researched:

- [item 2.5.15](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries)
- [How do I do a JPQL SubQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629259/how-do-i-do-a-jpql-subquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [item 5](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/query-complex-jpa-hibernate/)
- [item 10.2.5.15](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries)

[Using IN with a subquery](http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/introducing-jpql-part-3-ejb-3/)

I'm using EclipseLink version 2.5.2 (integrated with Netbeans 8.0.2), Glassfish 4.1, Java 1.7.0_71.

UPDATED

The UorPos entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UorPos", catalog = "DIAGE", schema = "ade")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="UorPos.findXByY", query="SELECT u FROM UorPos u WHERE u.prefixo IN
(SELECT j.prefixoJurisdicionada FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixo =
(SELECT j.prefixo FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixoJurisdicionada = :prefixo))
AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)")
})

public class UorPos implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "Matricula")
    private String matricula;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "Nome")
    private String nome;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "NomeGuerra")
    private String nomeGuerra;
    @Column(name = "CodComissao")
    private Integer codComissao;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "NomeComissao")
    private String nomeComissao;
    @Size(max = 4)
    @Column(name = "CodNivel")
    private String codNivel;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "DescNivel")
    private String descNivel;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "eMailFuncionario")
    private String eMailFuncionario;
    @Column(name = "DataCaptura")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCaptura;
    @Column(name = "DataPermissaoAcesso")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataPermissaoAcesso;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "uorPosCollection")
    private Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "uorPosCollection1")
    private Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection1;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "uorPosCollection2")
    private Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection2;
    @JoinColumn(name = "UORpos", referencedColumnName = "UORpos")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Divisoes uORpos;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPermissaoAcesso", referencedColumnName = "idPermissaoAcesso")
    @ManyToOne
    private PermissoesAcesso idPermissaoAcesso;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Prefixo", referencedColumnName = "Prefixo")
    @ManyToOne
    private Prefixos prefixo;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "matricula")
    private Collection<Anotacoes> anotacoesCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "matricula")
    private Collection<Log> logCollection;

    public UorPos() {
    }

    public UorPos(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNomeGuerra() {
        return nomeGuerra;
    }

    public void setNomeGuerra(String nomeGuerra) {
        this.nomeGuerra = nomeGuerra;
    }

    public Integer getCodComissao() {
        return codComissao;
    }

    public void setCodComissao(Integer codComissao) {
        this.codComissao = codComissao;
    }

    public String getNomeComissao() {
        return nomeComissao;
    }

    public void setNomeComissao(String nomeComissao) {
        this.nomeComissao = nomeComissao;
    }

    public String getCodNivel() {
        return codNivel;
    }

    public void setCodNivel(String codNivel) {
        this.codNivel = codNivel;
    }

    public String getDescNivel() {
        return descNivel;
    }

    public void setDescNivel(String descNivel) {
        this.descNivel = descNivel;
    }

    public String getEMailFuncionario() {
        return eMailFuncionario;
    }

    public void setEMailFuncionario(String eMailFuncionario) {
        this.eMailFuncionario = eMailFuncionario;
    }

    public Date getDataCaptura() {
        return dataCaptura;
    }

    public void setDataCaptura(Date dataCaptura) {
        this.dataCaptura = dataCaptura;
    }

    public Date getDataPermissaoAcesso() {
        return dataPermissaoAcesso;
    }

    public void setDataPermissaoAcesso(Date dataPermissaoAcesso) {
        this.dataPermissaoAcesso = dataPermissaoAcesso;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Demandas> getDemandasCollection() {
        return demandasCollection;
    }

    public void setDemandasCollection(Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection) {
        this.demandasCollection = demandasCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Demandas> getDemandasCollection1() {
        return demandasCollection1;
    }

    public void setDemandasCollection1(Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection1) {
        this.demandasCollection1 = demandasCollection1;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Demandas> getDemandasCollection2() {
        return demandasCollection2;
    }

    public void setDemandasCollection2(Collection<Demandas> demandasCollection2) {
        this.demandasCollection2 = demandasCollection2;
    }

    public Divisoes getUORpos() {
        return uORpos;
    }

    public void setUORpos(Divisoes uORpos) {
        this.uORpos = uORpos;
    }

    public PermissoesAcesso getIdPermissaoAcesso() {
        return idPermissaoAcesso;
    }

    public void setIdPermissaoAcesso(PermissoesAcesso idPermissaoAcesso) {
        this.idPermissaoAcesso = idPermissaoAcesso;
    }

    public Prefixos getPrefixo() {
        return prefixo;
    }

    public void setPrefixo(Prefixos prefixo) {
        this.prefixo = prefixo;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Anotacoes> getAnotacoesCollection() {
        return anotacoesCollection;
    }

    public void setAnotacoesCollection(Collection<Anotacoes> anotacoesCollection) {
        this.anotacoesCollection = anotacoesCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Log> getLogCollection() {
        return logCollection;
    }

    public void setLogCollection(Collection<Log> logCollection) {
        this.logCollection = logCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (matricula != null ? matricula.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof UorPos)) {
            return false;
        }
        UorPos other = (UorPos) object;
        if ((this.matricula == null && other.matricula != null) || (this.matricula != null && !this.matricula.equals(other.matricula))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.com.bb.uop.dcvipat.ade.entity.UorPos[ matricula=" + matricula + " ]";
    }

}
```

The Jurisdicionadas entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Jurisdicionadas", catalog = "DIAGE", schema = "ade")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Jurisdicionadas.findAll", query="SELECT j FROM Jurisdicionadas j")})
public class Jurisdicionadas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "PrefixoJurisdicionada")
    private Integer prefixoJurisdicionada;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "NomePrefixoJurisdicionada")
    private String nomePrefixoJurisdicionada;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Prefixo", referencedColumnName = "Prefixo")
    @ManyToOne
    private Prefixos prefixo;

    public Jurisdicionadas() {
    }

    public Jurisdicionadas(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPrefixoJurisdicionada() {
        return prefixoJurisdicionada;
    }

    public void setPrefixoJurisdicionada(Integer prefixoJurisdicionada) {
        this.prefixoJurisdicionada = prefixoJurisdicionada;
    }

    public String getNomePrefixoJurisdicionada() {
        return nomePrefixoJurisdicionada;
    }

    public void setNomePrefixoJurisdicionada(String nomePrefixoJurisdicionada) {
        this.nomePrefixoJurisdicionada = nomePrefixoJurisdicionada;
    }

    public Prefixos getPrefixo() {
        return prefixo;
    }

    public void setPrefixo(Prefixos prefixo) {
        this.prefixo = prefixo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Jurisdicionadas)) {
            return false;
        }
        Jurisdicionadas other = (Jurisdicionadas) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.com.bb.uop.dcvipat.ade.entity.Jurisdicionadas[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your `entities` code?

Comment: htshame, I've provided the related entities code. Do you - or someone else - have any hints ?

Comment: Do you really need `catalog` and `schema` in your entitty? Also, try editing your query as such: `SELECT u FROM UorPos u WHERE u.prefixo IN 
  (SELECT j.prefixoJurisdicionada FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixo = 
    (SELECT j2.prefixo FROM Jurisdicionadas j2 WHERE j2.prefixoJurisdicionada = :prefixo)) 
AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)`

Comment: Yes, I really need `catalog` and `schema` in my entities, the only problem here is thIS JPQL. I've already tried to query the way you hinted, but the Exception is the same :( . I also tried `SELECT u FROM UorPos u, Jurisdicionadas j  WHERE u.prefixo IN (SELECT j.prefixoJurisdicionada FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixo = (SELECT j.prefixo FROM Jurisdicionadas j WHERE j.prefixoJurisdicionada = :prefixo)) AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)`, but throws the same Exception. Help me.

Comment: Are you sure that there actually ARE the missing columns in the database? What is your hibernate setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` ?

Comment: I've already built and tested the T-SQL query, which is working fine, there's nothing missing. In fact, I was using this JPQL: `SELECT u FROM UorPos u WHERE u.prefixo = :prefixo AND u.codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347)` which works fine. The problem really is in the JPQL subquery. As I've already informed in the question: _I'm using EclipseLink version 2.5.2 (integrated with Netbeans 8.0.2), Glassfish 4.1, Java 1.7.0_71_. I did not tested using hibernate.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can add `nativeQuery=true` to your `@Query` and write your query as a plain SQL. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries

Comment: htshame, I'm so glad for your great hint about Native Queries, you've saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the great hint posted by htshame, I've researched about [Eclipselink Native SQL Queries](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native) and workarounded the problem as below:

```
    public List<UorPos> findUorPosExecutivosByPrefixo(Prefixos prefixo) {
    return (List<UorPos>) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM DIAGE.ade.UorPos WHERE prefixo IN (SELECT prefixoJurisdicionada FROM DIAGE.ade.Jurisdicionadas WHERE prefixo = (SELECT prefixo FROM DIAGE.ade.Jurisdicionadas WHERE prefixoJurisdicionada = ?)) AND codComissao IN (4345, 4346, 4347) ORDER BY nome, matricula", UorPos.class).setParameter(1, prefixo.getPrefixo()).getResultList();
}
```

But, if someone could resolve the JPQL named query issue, it will be better.